# Maybe Monad and >>=

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

The type signature for `>>=` is the following:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

And the following makes sense to me (it is also one of the monad laws):

```
(>>=) (Just 1) (id . return) == Just 1
```

Yet the Prelude gives the following:

```
Prelude> :t (>>=) (Just 1) id
(>>=) (Just 1) id :: Num (Maybe b) => Maybe b
```

I would have expected the Prelude to return some error as the type signature on id is `(a -> a)` as opposed to `Monad m => (a -> m b)`.

Is there a great way to understand what is going on here? Is there any use for `(>>=) (Just 1) id`?

Comment: It might help to notice that `m >>= id` is equivalent to `join m`, and `join` has signature `Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`.

Comment: They seem to differ slightly, no? ```(>>=) Just 1 $ id :: Num (Maybe (a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> b) => b``` versus ```join (Just 1) :: Num (Maybe a) => Maybe a```

Comment: You need more parentheses:  `(>>=) (Just 1) $ id` should come out the same.

Comment: @abhillman `(>>=) Just 1 $ id` is *not* the same as `(>>=) (Just 1) id`. The latter is your example above, and compare the type you listed in your question with the type of the `join` example.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Ah, got it. Yes. I see.

Comment: Still, I'm kind of confused as to why Prelude does not complain about the construct ```(>>=) (Just 1) id``` as id's return type is not specified to be in the monad type class.

Comment: `id` can have any return type, including monad types.

Comment: I suppose. But when id is called by `(>>=) (Just 1)`, it will be provided with a parameter that is *not* in the monad type class, no? And thus it should return something that is not in the monad type class?

Comment: `1` may be interpreted as any type that is a `Num`, but that type can _also_, in theory, be an instance of `Monad`.

Comment: So perhaps the Prelude is reading 1 as a ```Monad```? What would be a way to construct a number that is an instance of ```Monad``` — or is this only something the Prelude is able to do under the hood? Is it the case that anything can be an instance of ```Monad```?

Comment: Yes, anything can be an instance of `Monad`, and conversely, anything can be an instance of `Num`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70765/discussion-between-abhillman-and-louis-wasserman).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `id` is `c -> c` (using a different letter so not to conflict with `a` and `b` that occur in the type of `>>=`). We can unify `c -> c` with `a -> Maybe b` if we pick `c = a = Maybe b`.

So this means that `>>=` in your example is used at type:

```
(>>=) :: Maybe (Maybe b) -> (Maybe b -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
```

Now you have

```
(>>=)    (Just 1)           id
```

For `Just 1` to be of type `Maybe (Maybe b)`, `Maybe b` must be in `Num` (because then `1` can be interpreted as `Maybe b`).

Comment: Thanks, @kosmikus. Is there a great place to read about unifying types? I am not so familiar with the concept.

Comment: Also, would it be correct to say, then, that ```1``` is being interpreted as a monad?

Comment: @abhillman Depends on how theoretical and thorough you want to get. Pierce's "Types and programming languages" is really good and thorough. But if you're looking for a more casual intro, you might just want to look at Haskell books.

Comment: @abhillman I think that'd be a misleading statement. The type of `1` is `Num t => t`. So a literal can be interpreted as any type that is a member of the `Num` class. You're using `1` at type `Maybe b` in the example. That's why the requirement for `Maybe b` to be in `Num` arises (which usually does not hold). This has nothing to do with `Maybe` also being a monad.